# Bootstrap navbar doesn't expand while using bottom bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'am learning how to use bootstrap, but I have a problem with reponsiveness.
When I have my content wide it looks like my navbar doesn't expand to the right:

[image]

Here is code of my navbar:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: 5.0, but for on my previous projects with 4.4 it worked the same way

Comment: @humanbeing, I used bootstrap 5.0 and I'm unable to replicate your error; everything works fine. Which browser are you using? (I used firefox 85.0.1) Also, is there any other css that you are using? It could be interfering with bootstrap.

Comment: 84.0.2 under Ubuntu, but I have the same effect under Chrome. No other css. This is fresh project. Only authentication for now.

Comment: It works well when I stretch the window, but doesn't when I use bottom bar. Maybe I don't understand ideology behind it. My content isn't wrapped in any bootstrap class yet. I will check it after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put an id or a class and then select it in your css file. After that you can give
width: 100% or width: 100vw if these don't work u can use overflow-x: hidden;